# Changing parameter values before passing to stored procedure in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2012

I have a need to modify the values of a multi-value parameter (fed by end users during run time via a textbox) in a report before it gets passed to a stored procedure. So for example, if the user enters a number like '4444123', then I should be able to pad zeroes at the beginning and make its length equal to 10 ie. '0004444123'.

However, if the user enters something like 'AA4545', then, in that case, the value needs to be passed as it is. In short, if the value starts with a number, then pad it with extra zeroes, else make no change

I have been thinking of using some custom code for it, but can't figure out a way to return back the value to stored procedure. Handling it through SQL is not possible at this moment.

Comment: What will do if user enters 4444A12. Means starting with number but having alphabets. Here need to pad with zeros or leave it as it is?

Comment: There won't be any inputs like that, if it starts with a number, then the whole value will be numeric

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you hope to fix report parameter value end user inputted before executing the report? Probably below can solve your problem:

- A blank report (master report) with input parameter
- Embed a sub report into the master report
- Use expression to fix the parameter and then pass it into the sub
  report

However is the report calling from external application? If so the parameter value should be handled by the application, not the report.

Answer (score 0):

You can place this custom code function in the **Report -> Report Properties -> Code**. With the help of `StrDup` you can achieve your requirement. I'm checking your first character is numeric or not. If it numeric padding with zeros, if not simply return the passed parameter value.

The Function code is:

```
Function ConvertMutiValue(ByVal multivalue As String) As String
    Dim firstChar As String
    firstChar = LEFT(TRIM(multivalue), 1)

    Dim returnText As String
    returnText = multivalue 

    IF IsNumeric(firstChar) Then
        returnText = StrDup(10 - Len(multivalue), "0") + multivalue
    END IF

    Return returnText 
End Function
```

And call the function inside the **Dataset Properties -> Parameters -> Parameter Value's Expression**. I assumed `Multivalue` is your parameter name.

Sample screenshot for your reference.

[image]

Comment: it throws back an error saying 'Conversion from type Object() to type 'String' is not valid'.

Comment: Could you try this `Function ConvertMutiValue(ByVal multivalue as Parameter) As String`. I mentioned `multivalue` as `Parameter` instead of `String`

Comment: nope, even that doesn't work; give out error as "Value of type 'Microsoft.ReortingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportObjectModel.Parameter' cannot be converted to 'String'''

Comment: It means instead of `multivalue` need to use `multivalue.Value` inside the function

Comment: still not working...this is what i have done `Function ConvertMutiValue(ByVal multivalue As Parameter) As String
    Dim firstChar As String
    firstChar = LEFT(TRIM(multivalue.Value), 1)

    Dim returnText As String
    returnText = multivalue.Value 

    IF IsNumeric(firstChar) Then
        returnText = StrDup(10 - Len(multivalue.Value), "0") + multivalue.Value
    END IF

    Return returnText 
End Function`

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using the function given here [restrict duplicates in the parameters ssrs](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/deb57780-7f8d-4db9-a254-0ef2b43d8772/restrict-duplicates-in-the-parameters-ssrs?forum=sqlreportingservices)